# Database Entry from Excel sheet with help of symfony

Tags: php, mysql, excel, symfony

If I have 14000 records  then there is memory space issue coming and if records are 1000 I am able to upload but takes 00:30 mints .

Can anyone help me to optimize this code that I can upload records in minimum  time?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace ProjectName\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;


class TakeoverController extends Controller {



    public function uploadtakeoverAction(Request $request) {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //0=NOLIMIT

        ini_set('memory_limit', '8192M');
        //start - code to check ip address
        $checkipaddress = $this->get('userlogin')->CheckIPAddress();
        if (empty($checkipaddress)) {

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin'));
        }
        //end - code to check ip address
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $helper = $this->get('common_helper_function');
        $reqImage = $_FILES;

        $validExtensions = array('xls', 'xlsx');
        if (isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES)) {
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if (!in_array($ext, $validExtensions)) {
                echo "1";
                die;
            }
        }

        $admin = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $takeoverfile = $this->uploadtakeoverFile($reqImage);
        $takeovertm = array();
        $insertedrecord = array();
        $existingrecord = array();
        $importmulitpletakeover = array();
        $atmservicesamount = array();
        $errormessage = '';
        $neeerro = '';
        if ($takeoverfile) {

            $phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject();
            $file = $takeoverfile;
            if (!file_exists($file)) {
                exit("Please run 05featuredemo.php first.");
            }

            $objPHPExcel = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);

            foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

                    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
                    $totalindex = $row->getRowIndex();
                    //   echo $row->getRowIndex();
                    if ($row->getRowIndex() != 1) { // first index is title index so not cosider

                        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {

                            if (!is_null($cell)) {
//the below columns are from A to AF
                                if ($cell->getColumn() == 'A') {                                  
                                    $val1= trim($cell->getValue());
                                }

                                if ($cell->getColumn() == 'B') {
                                    $val2= $cell->getValue();
                                }

                                if ($cell->getColumn() == 'C') {
                                    $val3= trim($cell->getValue());
                                }
                                if ($cell->getColumn() == 'D') {
                                    $val3.=', ' . trim($cell->getValue());
                                }
                                if ($cell->getColumn() == 'E') {
                                    $val3.=', ' . trim($cell->getValue());                                  
                                }


                            }
// insert this fields into database  from here of column A to AF

                        }

            unlink($takeoverfile);
            $response = new Response(json_encode($importmulitpletakeover));
            return $response;
        } else {
            $message = 'Image has not been uploaded ';
            echo "2";
            die;
        }
    }
}}}
    protected function uploadtakeoverFile($uploadedReceipt) {

        //start - code to check ip address
        $checkipaddress = $this->get('userlogin')->CheckIPAddress();
        if (empty($checkipaddress)) {

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin'));
        }
        //end - code to check ip address

        $basicPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ProjectName/web/uploads';
        $basicReceiptPath = $basicPath . '/FolderName';

        if (null === $uploadedReceipt) {
            return;
        } else {
            $extention = explode('.', @$uploadedReceipt['file']["name"]);
            $filename = @$extention[0] . '_' . time() . '.' . @$extention[1];
            $this->path = $basicReceiptPath . '/' . @$filename;
            if (move_uploaded_file($uploadedReceipt['file']["tmp_name"], $this->path))
                return $this->path;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most effective style will be to only use Doctrine DBAL and write SQL code.

[Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) states that Doctrine ORM is not fit for mass inserts.

There are "hacks" like disabling SQLLogger and batch processing, but using only DBAL will save you more time.